# Wildcards support for AllowedCorsOrigins in IdentityServer4

Tags: .net, cors, openid-connect, identityserver4, identity

I use IdentityServer4 to login to my app using authorization_code flow.

I need to add support of wildcards for AllowedCorsOrigins in IdentityServer4 client configuration. I created my implementation of ICorsPolicyService, registered it in Startup. I checked that this code runs and returns true.

But when I add wildcard to AllowedCorsOrigins setting, it doesn't allow me to log in. Instead of login form I see this error message: "unauthorized_client. Unknown client or client not enabled"

It looks like it checks for AllowedCorsOrigins somewhere else. How I can make it work?

**Updated**: I see this in logs:

> AllowedCorsOrigins contains invalid origin:
> http://local*ost:4200","SourceContext":"Duende.IdentityServer.Stores.ValidatingClientStore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I need to write my own implementation of IClientConfigurationValidator and register it using AddClientConfigurationValidator.

```
public class CustomClientConfigurationValidator : DefaultClientConfigurationValidator
{
    public CustomClientConfigurationValidator(IdentityServerOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override Task ValidateAllowedCorsOriginsAsync(ClientConfigurationValidationContext context)
    {
        // Validation code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is both a CORS setting in ASP.NET Core for ASP.NET core things and and one inside IdenttityServer, and in it you define inside the client definition.

https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/models/client/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question is not how to remove wildcard from AllowedCorsOrigins setting, but how to make it working with it.

Comment: If I am not wrong, I think there are some issues with CORS and the order of the modules in the ASP.NET requestpipeline ,meaning, if you should place AddCors() before or after  app.UseIdentityServer();

Comment: AddCors is in ConfigureServices method and UseIdentityServer is in Configure method

Comment: I mean UseCors and UseIdentityServer, the order of those two may matter, just something I remember from the past